# Sort YAML file with comments

Tags: yaml, pyyaml, ruamel.yaml

### 1. Summary

I can't find, how I can sort YAML file with comments.

Solutions, that I can find:

1. delete comments,

   **or**
2. save comments not after right line.

---

### 2. Example

I have a file `SashaSort.yaml`:

```yaml
sasha: great
# Kristina comment
kristina: legendary
katya: 'Вечная память'
```

---

### 3. Expected behavior

```yaml
katya: 'Вечная память'
# Kristina comment
kristina: legendary
sasha: great
```

(*Non-ASCII symbols must be saved*.)

---

### 4. Not helped

1. Answers to this question [**not save comments**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7275952/5951529) as expected,
2. [**yml-sorter**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yml-sorter) and [**PyYAML**](http://pyyaml.org/) delete comments,
3. if I use [**i18n_yaml_sorter**](https://github.com/redealumni/i18n_yaml_sorter), I get output:

   ```yaml
   katya: 'Вечная память'
   kristina: legendary
   sasha: great
   # Kristina comment
   ```

   Comment save not above `kristina: legendary` line.

   Write issue uselessly, because last commit in i18n_yaml_sorter [**make in 2011**](https://github.com/redealumni/i18n_yaml_sorter/commits/master).
4. [**I can't find, how I can sort YAML in `ruamel.yaml` documentation**](http://yaml.readthedocs.io/en/latest/search.html?q=sort&check_keywords=yes&area=default),
5. I can't find sort option in [**`ruamel.yaml.cmd`**](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ruamel.yaml.cmd).

Comment: In ruamel.yaml comments are associated with the key/value pair before them (assuming the simple scalar values as you have). Thus `# Kristina comment` is a comment on `sasha: great` and not on `kristina: legendary` (of course no interpretation on the contents is done).

Comment: @Anthon, `In ruamel.yaml comments are associated with the key/value pair before them` — What can I do, that associated comments with the key/value pair **after** them. [**Most of peoples**](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/126603/264224) and me prefer comments above the code they refer to. Thanks.

Comment: Since the node following the comment is not available when parsing YAML, I associate the comment with the node before it (either on the same line, or on the previous line). This is more like a Python docstring. For the purpose of ruamel.yaml (load a YAML file, change a value, dump to file) that is enough. I have considered moving lines after an empty line in a run of comment-only-lines to the following key/element, but there is currently no mechanism for that. You will have to associate the comment with the key that will end up before your target key after after sorting, thus with `katya`.

Comment: @Anthon, **1.** `Since the node following the comment is not available when parsing YAML, I associate the comment with the node before it (either on the same line, or on the previous line). This is more like a Python docstring.` — Where I can read it in more details? I can't find it in Google. // **2.** OK, how I can sort my YAML file, where comments associated with the key/value pair before them, use `ruamel.yaml`? Thanks.

Comment: I raised a feature request at "js-yaml" to preserve comments when sorting: https://github.com/nodeca/js-yaml/issues/689

Answer (score 0):

[PyYAML](https://pypi.org/project/PyYAML/) doesn't support comments.

[ruamel.yaml](https://pypi.org/project/ruamel.yaml/) does support, but it requires some efforts for sorting. Main point about comments that *in* `ruamel.yaml` they refer to the current line or line above:

```yaml
- one # comment to the current line
# comment to the line above (one)
- two
```

So you should reorganize parser results (and learn some guts of keeping comments). I created a module [`comments_sort.py`](https://github.com/maxx27/pyyaml-sort/blob/main/comments_sort.py) to simplify this process. You can see the [demo script](https://github.com/maxx27/pyyaml-sort/blob/main/demo.py). As for requested example, it will look like the following:

```py
import sys

import ruamel.yaml
from comments_sort import map_sort_before

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()

yaml_str = """\
sasha: great
# Kristina comment
kristina: legendary
katya: 'Вечная память'
"""

obj = yaml.load(yaml_str)
sorted_keys = sorted(
    list(obj.keys()),
    key=lambda x: x,
)
obj_sorted = map_sort_before(obj, sorted_keys)
yaml.dump(obj_sorted, sys.stdout)
```

Output is:

```
katya: Вечная память
# Kristina comment
kristina: legendary
sasha: great
```

For reverse sorting:

```py
...
sorted_keys = sorted(
    list(obj.keys()),
    key=lambda x: x,
    reverse=True,
)
...
```

Output is:

```
sasha: great
# Kristina comment
kristina: legendary
katya: Вечная память
```